# Not getting expected results from list popping in a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Why is this only returning some of the items?

```
lst = ["!apple", "!green", "!blue", "one"]
new_list = [lst.pop(idx) for idx,i in enumerate(lst) if i.startswith("!")]
print(new_list)
```

Returns:

```
['!apple', '!blue']
```

Comment: don't modify a list while iterating on it

Comment: Yes, collections should not be mutated during iteration. Note that others have raised concerns that Python documentation is not clear enough on this matter. Ref: https://bugs.python.org/issue32767

Comment: Interesting and thank you. I wasn't aware of this.